# HTML5 Canvas not displaying images when meta tag present

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, canvas

HTML5 canvas (only using the drawImage function) is not showing up on mobile devices, but is on my laptop.

I get no errors or anything, but it doesn't display in chrome on iOS or the default browser on android..

This problem only occurs when the following meta tag is included in the document:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
```

With meta tag : [mmhudson.com/index.html](http://mmhudson.com/index.html)

Without: [mmhudson.com/index1.html](http://mmhudson.com/index1.html)

Comment: Bit of an odd one. Are you sure you aren't having cashing problems on the mobile devices? The only other thing I could suggest would be to implement your meta tag correctly (oh and to add a doctype just because it's good practice). `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` (i.e. there is no close `</meta>` tag). I don't really see how this would affect it though. btw you second link is pointing to the first link.

Comment: This shows up just fine on my ipad

Comment: @pebbl You mean caching problems? How would I test for this? I removed the closing tag and added a doctype, but nothing changed. It appears the images just aren't loading.

Comment: @maxhud - yes apologies for the typo :) easiest way to test for caching issues is to change the URLs involved by adding query strings to the end. So request http://mmhudson.com/index.html?q=1 instead, also you should do the same for your page assets i.e. like images, so http://mmhudson.com/images/a.png?q=1 -- as I said, only a guess though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more differences between those two pages than just the meta tag.

Specifically, the one with the meta tag does **not** have a `ontouchstart` event.